# HTML/CSS Button and A link vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically center `<button>` and `<a>` elements. I use CSS inline-block property for each. Strangly, my `<a>` link is shifted down.

```css
button,
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #00ade0;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button>
  1
</button>
<button>
  2
</button>
<a href="#" class="btn">
  3
</a>
```

I know if I change the line-height, it can resolve the problem, but I dont know why with `line-height:0`, I cant acheive what a want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this. Wrap your `buttons` and `a` tag in a container and use flex properties. I've also added `box-sizing: border-box` for consistency across elements. Let me know if you have any questions.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

button,
.btn {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #00ade0;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>
    1
  </button>
  <button>
    2
  </button>
  <a href="#" class="btn">
  3
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to your specifying a `width` and `height` though there are other superfluous declarations (like browser-specific declarations for `border-radius`).  If we replace the `width` and `height` with padding though... you get more consistent results:`

```css
button, .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #00ade0;

    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 999px;
    
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 1.5rem Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button>
  1
</button>
<button>
  2
</button>
<a href="#" class="btn">
  3
</a>
```

I changed your `border-radius` to be an absurdly high number in pixels as (in my experience) this seems to provide more consistency than percentages when trying to achieve true circles. For consistency I also added `box-sizing`, and specified a font for all of the items, as `<button>` seems to have a browser-defined font that may differ from the default (which would be used for `<a>`)

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution and seem working! :) Just wondering why height cause the offset positionning problem.

Comment: It's a combination problem of browser defaults and `line-height`.  The former is causing your anchor link to render text in a different default font, and the `line-height` exacerbates that.  By unifying the font across `<button>` and `.btn` and removing the line height, width, and height in lieu of padding we resolve all those potential issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I am just wondering why to use an `<a>` element when you already have `<button>` elements. It displays properly with little modifications on your HTML/CSS.
Here it comes for your HTML code :

```
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
```

And your CSS :

```
 button
 {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   margin-left: 10px;
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #00ade0;
   border: 2px solid #fff;
   height: 4rem;
   width: 4rem;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
   -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
   -moz-border-radius: 50%;
   border-radius: 50%;
  }
```

By putting an `<a>` element, i presume you want to add a click action on your buttons. If it's the case, you can do it with a little Javascript like this :

```
var buttons = document.body.querySelectorAll('button');
  for(var i = 0, c = buttons.length; i < c; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      //Redirect user with your links here
    });
  }
```

Comment: I use links and buttons, for accessibility and semantic purpose. Buttons is for actions on page and link to reach another page. Thanks for your answer!